# Why do cats wear scarves in anime?

Tags: tropes

1. Sakamoto from *Nichijou*

[image]

2. The cat from *Ninja Hattori* (Note: I don't remember the details but I knew an episode where the cat was heartbroken because he lost the scarf and thought that his master would abandon him)

[image]

Why do cats wear scarves in anime? What does it signify? Does it signify that it is domesticated/adopted? The color of the scarf is mostly red. Why?

---

Happy from *Fairy Tail* also wears something which is sort of a backpack used to carry food and items for battle:

[image]

Comment: Well, Sakamoto's scarf is the device that allows him to talk, created by Hakase.

Answer (score 1):

***So they stand out from other, normal Cats.***

Similar how many Protagonists in Anime have a different hair color, eye color or some other special feature, and many Girls have varying hair-colors so they contrast from their
predominantly brown / black haired normal Classmates.

***So they appear more human.***

By giving them human-like characteristics, like wearing accessories, they appear more civilized, intelligent and human like.

***Because we do this in real-life to, I guess.***

Some people just like to dress up their dogs and cats, so it wouldn't be impossible for Anime-Characters to have the same ideas?